# Running Dynamics AX Test Case in C#

Tags: c#, .net, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++

I am hoping someone out there can give me help with this. So I need to be able to run Microsoft Dynamics AX test case in C#. Now I was going to try and do something like

`Process.Start("ax32.exe", "-StartupCmd=RunTestProject_<name of test>");`

But I am hoping there might be a way to run it by importing some Dynamics AX DLL in C# and executing the test cases that way with something like SysTestRunner (right now I think this only exists in x++/MorphX).

ANY hints or hunches or potential solutions to this problem are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!!

Comment: I agree with @Skaue - Can you say more about what problem you are trying to solve by calling test cases from C#?

Comment: Essentially the goal is to run AX test cases in Visual Studio so they can be managed in the VS environment. We are leveraging the functionality of the Generic Tests in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone comes across this issue we ended up just going with the

```
Process.Start("ax32.exe", "-StartupCmd=RunTestProject_<name of test>");
```

since this was the best way to gain access to DynamicsAX internals and actually invoke the test cases. Unfortunately the DynamicsAX splash screen will come up with every invocation but that was something we were willing to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate more on what you want to achieve by running the tests from C#? If you want to run daily/nightly tests, you could simply do this running a batch within Dynamics AX.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.

Comment: Yes, maybe. But there is no "comment" link on the initial question. I could however comment this answer. Strange... :-/